# vpxmt.lib for vs2012 1.3

Tags: c++, windows, libvpx

3 vpxmt.lib for 2012.  I've tried to build it but I keep running into new problems. It seems like one of those projects that will take a long time to setup with one dependency issue after another.  I'm wondering if someone either has the .lib files that can post or can tell me how to solve this next problem.

I was following the guide here:

http://www.webmproject.org/code/build-prerequisites/

I was able to produce vpx.sln in the .lib directory. But when I convert and build the project I get these 100's of these errors.
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'vpxmt.lib'

This is like the 6th dependency issue I've run into.

PS: Honestly if google actually actually wants vp9 to be taken up they should just provide us with prebuild libraries on windows (I imagine linux people are use to this) and not make us spend days trying to get the correct configuration settings.

Comment: ***fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'vpxmt.lib'*** Are you sure you are not mixing 32 and 64 bit. I mean if you are building for x64 a 32 bit library is no good same goes for the reverse.

Comment: Ok I was able to build.  I had to copy the 1.2 yasm 32 bit into the folder of the solution instead of the newer 1.3 which doesn't work.  I also had to rename it to yasm.  Why in this day and age do we have to jump through so many hoops to add a library?